# Self hosted project community alternatives

Tags: project-management, wiki, bug-tracking, hosted

I am looking for a self hosted CodePlex clone to use on an intranet.
It should be web-based, preferably open-source but may also be commercial.

The important features I need are:

- Discussion board
- Wiki for project documentation
- Mercurial integration (optional)
- Issue tracker (optional)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some alternatives I found:

- Redmine (open source, can be easily installed through BitNami Installer)
- TRAC (open source)
- JIRA (Commercial)
- GitHub Enterprise (Commercial)

I am currently evaluating Redmine.